# Pixel minigame to embed on website

Tags: javascript, html, game, react

I am looking for the source of a small videogame I can embedd on a onepage website.
I am looking for something very simple like pong, or an 8-bit kind of arkanoid.
The goal is to embed it on a small project I have (one page website, ideally static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the Awesome Self Hosted list? https://github.com/awesome-selfhosted/awesome-selfhosted

I believe you can find something suitable under **"Games"** heading.

Comment: looks pretty cool, ill take a look

Comment: not much games content, some too flashy and elaborate, more than pong or arkanoid at least

Comment: This one has MIT license check it out. Two player pong game: https://github.com/toivjon/html5-pong